# SocailEngine Signup Process

Tags: socialengine

I have changed the signup process is in existing social engine signup process is three-step (Create Account, Personal Information, Photo).

But as per my project requirement made changes is show only step-1.

My problem is Email verification email is not sending after a click on step-1 submit button.

When I follow the three-step signup process then Email verification mail is sending properly.

SocialEngine Version: 4.10

Comment: It's done using added send verification mail logic in Step - 1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  I have done using custom logic